# Modifying large csv in chunks?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I get an error 'TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object does not support item assignment' when I try to add columns and modify header names etc in chunks.

My issue is I am using a slow work laptop to process a pretty large file (10 million rows). I want to add some simple columns (1 or 0 values), concatenate two columns to create a unique ID, change the dtype for other columns, and rename some headers so they match with other files that I will .merge later. I could probably split this csv (maybe select date ranges and make separate files), but I would like to learn how to use chunksize or deal with large files in general without running into memory issues. Is it possible to modify a file in chunks and then concatenate them all together later?

I am doing a raw data clean up which will then be loaded into Tableau for visualization.

Example (reading/modifying 10 million rows):

```
    > rep = pd.read_csv(r'C:\repeats.csv.gz',
    > compression = 'gzip', parse_dates = True , usecols =
    > ['etc','stuff','others','...'])
    > rep.sort() 
    > rep['Total_Repeats'] = 1
    > rep.rename(columns={'X':'Y'}, inplace = True)
    > rep.rename(columns={'Z':'A'}, inplace = True)
    > rep.rename(columns={'B':'C'}, inplace = True)
    > rep['D']= rep['E'] + rep['C']
    > rep.rename(columns={'L':'M'}, inplace = True)
    > rep.rename(columns={'N':'O'}, inplace = True)
    > rep.rename(columns={'S':'T'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: How are you currently doing it? Can you provide some sample mode?

Comment: Edited my post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `chunk_size` keyword to pd.read_csv, it returns iterator of csv reader. and you can write processed chunks with `to_csv` method in append mode. you will be able to process large file, but you can't sort dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv(r'C:\repeats.csv.gz',
    compression = 'gzip', parse_dates=True, chunk_size=10000
    usecols = ['etc','stuff','others','...'])

output_path = 'output.csv'

for chunk_df in reader:
    chunk_result = do_somthing_with(chunk_df)
    chunk_result.to_csv(output_path, mode='a', header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's usually pretty good with that as long as you ignore the .read() part when looking at large files.

If you just use the iterators, you should be fine:

```
with open('mybiginputfile.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
     with open('mybigoutputfile.txt', 'wt') as out_file:
           for row in in_file:
               'do something'
               out_file.write(row)
```

Someone who knows more will explain how the memory side of it works, but this works for me on multi GB files without crashing Python.

You might want to chuck the data into a proper DB before killing your laptop with the task of serving up the data AND running Tableau too!

Comment: Do you have a corresponding pandas code? Unfortunately, I am completely new to coding. This was to solve some problems with efficiency at work (we are an Excel based organization) and I learned some pandas on my own. I don't have much understanding of the fundamentals but I find it very valuable to clean up our files and such (compared to opening things individually in Excel).

Comment: Sorry - I haven't played much with pandas yet. Suspect you may have some fun with Blaze: http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/latest/data.html

Comment: In terms of how the memory works. The `for row in_file` method reads a file line by line into memory, discarding the previous line as it moves on. As a result you never have more than a line of the current file in memory at a time, resulting in an efficient way to ready massive files. Also for CSVs consider using the CSV built in module which has a specific CSV parser.